# Reverse Expression.Like criterion

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

How should I go about writing a backwards like statement using NHibernate criteria?

```
WHERE 'somestring' LIKE [Property] + '%'
```

#### Sub Question:

Can you access the abstract root alias in a SQLCriterion expression?

---

This is somewhat achievable using the SQLCriterion expression

```
Expression.Sql("? like {alias}.[Property] + '.%'", value, NHibernateUtil.String);
```

However, in the case of class inheritance, `{alias}` is replaced with the incorrect alias for the column.

Example (these classes are stored in separate tables):

```
public abstract class Parent 
{
    public virtual string Property { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent { }
```

The above query executed with `Child` as the root type will replace `{alias}` with the alias to the `Child` table rather than the `Parent` table. This results in an invalid column exception.

I need to execute a like statement as above where the property exists on the parent table rather than on the root type table.

Comment: +1, I am also interested if a solution to this exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the NOT (!) in front of the operator for the one you want but don't want. i think it might work.

Comment: `Expression.Not(Expression.Like("Property", value, MatchMode.StartsWith))`? That's not the same thing.